# Java persistent and serializable coonection

Tags: java, sockets, serialization

In Java it is better to create a new connection for transferring objects or i can make one connection persistent and serializable and use that only for tranferring objects? please help i am not able to find appropriate answer.

Comment: Your question is too vague.  You don't supply any context for your question so it will be impossible for anyone to advise on whatever scenario you are trying to deal with.

Comment: i am tryng to transfer logs of files which are successfully send.

Comment: What have you tried?  What did you observe?  Even with your comment, your question is still extremely vague.  Consider things like how many logs, how often they are generated, how big are they, what environment is your code running in, etc, etc, etc.  Your question in its current form is almost like asking which color is better, red or blue?

Comment: They are getting generated frequently if the file is transferred between same server and if files are transferred between two servers they are generated rarely.they contain all the information related to files like Name, start time, size etc.              I observed that transferring files using same connection will be helpful as creating new connection will consume more and more resources.

Answer (score 0):

> i can make one connection persistent

Yes.

> and serializable

No.